# How to find when a user has upvoted or downvoted a chatter post

Tags: community, chatter, chatter-feed

We are having a public community hosted on Salesforce and we are trying to create a custom report which would allow us to find unique contributors to the community. One of the criteria apart from creating a unique post and answering those posts is to also account for if the user has upvoted the post on a particular day.

I have been able to find ways in which we can check if the chatter post was upvoted by a specific user but it does not provide the timestamp of when it was done, which is important to identify when the contribution was done.

[image]

Would like to know if there any ways we can capture these details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked the URI endpoint behavior in my org:

> /services/data/v50.0/connect/communities/0DB7F000000CbHSWA0/chatter/feed-elements/0D57F00004rK1OpSAK/capabilities/up-down-vote

Upon reaching out to our product development team internally, got a confirmation that the ability to fetch the timestamp at which a specific user upvoted/downvoted on a chatter post on the community is currently not available.

Appreciate you taking the time to submit this as an Idea on [Salesforce Ideas exchange](https://success.salesforce.com/ideasearch) so that Salesforce can continue to improve the product.

Comment: Thanks, Swetha for looking into this.